# Find quantile bracket threshold R

Tags: r, quantile, percentile, weighted

I have a dataset where people are stored in income group like this :

```
test<-tibble(income_group = c(1:3), pop = c(20,25,10),max_income_from=c(100,200,500))
```

And would like to know if there is a function to retrieve the percentile corresponding to each value (here 20/55 people earn less than 200 so 200 would be the 36th percentile and 500 the 82th)

for now I use `cumsum(test$pop)/sum(test$pop)` but it looks quite ugly and I wondered if there is a function for weighted percentile calculations.

thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ecdf()` for this. In the `ecdf()` function you specify the distribution 1:55 (the sum of the population) and then pass the vector of cumulative sums for the population. This might be 'uglier' than your solution but it is an alternative.

```
ecdf(1:sum(test$pop))(cumsum(test$pop))
```

Another option is to use the `ewcdf()` function from spatstat.geom. you can pass income group as the observations, population as the weight, and then pass the vector of income and get the same result.

```
library(spatstat.geom)
ewcdf(test$income_group, weights = test$pop)(test$income_group)
```